# How to detect a hot streak in a pattern of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

This is more of an algorithmic question where say you have a pattern like 4 6 2 4 9 5 23 54 33 the last three numbers a hot streak. I'm wondering how this can be programmatically (or mathematically) detected.

At the moment I'm thinking of scanning the data with a trailing average of let's say past 3 values. If the new value (23) is suddenly a lot higher than that average we flag the start of a possible streak. The numbers following should not deviate too much from it to consider the hot streak as continuing.

Does this sound like an efficient approach? Are there any algorithms already in existence for such problems?

Comment: Any requirement to results of the algorithm? Like minimum number count to be a hot streak? Your idea: What would you do with 1 1 1 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 1... it would not recognize the end

Comment: Two or three would count as a hot streak. So the above sequence would have the 10, 9 count as streaky.

Comment: can you give a more precise formulation of what you would consider a hot streak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright. I have given this a shot but before I start I must say that this is not based on any algorithm (at least: I haven't knowingly based it on an existing algorithm) and there are some flaws in it (it doesn't account for negative numbers/zero) and there are probably many edge cases to resolve.

In order to find the distance between two numbers to determine whether or not they are similar I have found [this simple formula](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/data-quality/edqhelp/Content/processor_library/matching/comparisons/percent_difference.htm):

> Percent difference = (L - S) / S

where L stands for 'largest' and S for 'smallest'.

First of all, the output for 5 random sequences of 50 values between 1 and 40:

```
7 14 34 13 4 1 3 34 10 29 25 32 28 39 14 32 37 30 21 27 28 27 26 25 27 34 15 36 3 29 32 35 8 32 20 5 30 4 17 16 27 35 7 34 7 37 14 31 38 23 
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,95): 27 - 28 - 27
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,95): 28 - 27 - 26
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,95): 27 - 26 - 25

9 16 17 3 11 19 28 10 25 10 25 6 31 21 37 29 24 35 20 9 2 34 14 6 1 33 21 31 19 30 20 23 38 19 21 16 19 6 21 1 17 20 18 7 30 22 4 26 37 17 
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,8): 17 - 20 - 18

14 18 12 30 22 15 3 12 3 18 38 36 31 35 30 3 8 13 39 21 11 19 14 19 31 22 16 7 15 19 29 34 33 2 16 3 12 8 37 6 14 7 4 4 2 21 29 22 17 27 
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,8): 38 - 36 - 31
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,8): 36 - 31 - 35
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,8): 31 - 35 - 30
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,8): 29 - 34 - 33

14 31 26 16 6 35 5 32 38 39 38 35 36 24 29 4 3 29 20 28 31 39 15 34 8 4 15 11 18 11 32 34 30 28 5 38 9 17 35 21 37 19 9 37 8 18 11 20 14 37 
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,95): 38 - 39 - 38

18 39 3 29 36 14 17 32 9 3 20 33 15 28 8 5 6 9 19 30 35 25 34 38 30 13 30 17 27 29 33 35 36 20 33 33 31 2 31 30 21 16 9 33 2 5 4 21 30 3 
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,9): 33 - 35 - 36
Possible hot streak (treshold 0,9): 33 - 33 - 31
```

The idea I incorporated is fairly straightforward: given a list of items, iterate over it, group the first 3 starting from your current index and see if they are within the acceptable treshold. If they are, continue until you've found all combinations within the current treshold. If there are no combinations with the set treshold, subtract 0.05 from the treshold (aka: be more lenient) and start over.

It should be noted that this algorithm basically searches for a normalized group of values in the sequence. You can improve this by - after running the algorithm -, calculating the sum of the 3 values that are considered a hot streak and take the largest sum of the values in that treshold. This should give you the highest streak.

So what this algorithm does is finding streaks, all you have to do is find the hot streaks (which is trivial).

There are some more aspects where it could be improved to take only the sequences that have low surrounding values but this will depend on how far you want to take the algorithm.

One benefit of this approach is that it already partially does this (you'll notice that the sequences are often in the higher parts of the total dataset) because of the formula used to determine the difference between two numbers.

Values 3 and 2 will return a percentage difference of 0.5 whereas values 30 and 29 will be 0.03 so the latter one will be picked up by the algorithm a lot sooner. In this aspect you're already automatically gathering the hot streaks but it is not taking the surrounding values into account for even more preciseness.

The code:

```cs
void Main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var list = GetList();
        DisplayList(list);
        GetHotStreaks(list);
    }
}

private static Random rand = new Random();

private List<int> GetList(){
    var list = new List<int>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        list.Add(rand.Next(1, 40));
    }
    return list;
}

private void DisplayList(List<int> list){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++){
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private void GetHotStreaks(List<int> list){
    double treshold = 0.95;
    bool found = false;

    while(treshold > 0.0){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.Count - 2; i++){
            if(AreWithinRange(list[i], list[i + 1], list[i + 2], treshold)){
                Console.WriteLine (string.Format("Possible hot streak (treshold {0}): {1} - {2} - {3}", treshold, list[i], list[i + 1], list[i + 2]));
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if(found){
            Console.WriteLine ();
            return;
        }

        treshold -= 0.05;
    }   
}

private bool AreWithinRange(int val1, int val2, int val3, double treshold){
    return AreWithinRange(val1, val2, treshold) && AreWithinRange(val2, val3, treshold);
}

// http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/data-quality/edqhelp/Content/processor_library/matching/comparisons/percent_difference.htm
private bool AreWithinRange(int val1, int val2, double treshold){
    double max = Math.Max(val1, val2);
    double min = Math.Min(val1, val2);
    double pd = (max - min) / min;

    //Console.WriteLine ("Values: val1: {0}\t val2: {1}\t PD: {2}\t T: {3}", val1, val2, pd, treshold);
    return pd <= 1 - treshold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [FIR filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response), specifically discrete-time FIR filters.

Basically they are a generalized version of your algorithm (if I understand it correctly).

You will need to define more strictly when a streak is considered *hot* (if you see that as a qualitative attribute). FIR filters are quite established in signal processing and will (if used with the correct parameters) basically output a score that is equal to the *hotness* of the current streak.

This assumes you don't impose any strict limit on the streak length but you want a score that depends on the streak length.

FIRs can also detect streaks that are interrupted, I'm not sure if this is required in your usecase.

I think your algorithm might have problems if the streak doesn't start that suddenly, so your threshold for flagging the streak start might not be exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not unlike what stock traders are searching for when they are looking for a stock that has an unexpected jump in price (and, usually, volume).

[Moving averages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)
A Simple Moving Average just averages the past n numbers. In contrast, an Exponential Moving Average weights the last numbers much more heavily than the first.

I would suggest a ratio of EMA to SMA with a ratio greater than, say, 2 indicating a hot streak.

One could also use a shorter, faster-moving moving average versus a longer, slower-moving average. When the faster crosses over the slower, you might start looking for a hot streak.

[Oscillators](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/technical/070301.asp)
An oscillator can inform you when a price is at the top or bottom of its range.

I would suggest a Relative Strength Index of above 70 indicating a hot streak.